# is it possible to access props that haven't been passed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

Is it possible to access this prop "showPopover" somehow? from the constructor or so? The prop has been created in a seperate component and it works, but now that I've added in this component I wanted to hear if there is a simple way to get this prop, for modifying it.

[image]

Comment: cant tell by your provided screen, should be as easy as `xyz.showPopover`

Comment: edited the description, does it make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

*I cannot add comment due to less reputation so I am answering it on answer section*

Your question description is not proper. Please ask question with proper description.

I think it must be accessed by something like

`propName.showPopover`

To know more about comp and prop, I recommend you to visit docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

or you can visit medium blogs too, like https://medium.com/@PhilipAndrews/react-how-to-access-props-in-a-functional-component-6bd4200b9e0b